# Dockerfile Dynamic Registry for Image

Tags: docker, registry, private, dockerfile

Is there way to set up the registry dynamically in the FROM statement of Dockerfile?

We set up two private registries, one for prod ready images and one for development/stage. I am looking for a simple way to change image resource (as well as target) according environment or parameters of building/deploying job.

A doable way, I think about, is having docker pull and docker tag before docker build. Is there any better way?

Thanks,

Tiger

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that in the Dockerfile. The tag-before-build option is an option but mostly people do this with `make` or something similar - to modify the Dockerfile before building it (or spawn multiple Dockerfiles from one template for different images).

Have a look at [INCLUDEs in Dockerfiles with m4 and Make](http://bobbynorton.com/posts/includes-in-dockerfiles-with-m4-and-make/) to give you an idea.